# App opening but not working on Physical Device

Tags: java, android, exception

I am new to Android Development and am learning to use Android Studio. I am developing a simple app which tells the price of the number of coffee cups ordered. When I run the app on the virtual device it works perfectly fine but has a problem when I run it on my phone. The app loads properly but when I tap on the 'Order' button, I get an error: "Unfortunately, Just Java has stopped." When I googled,I got to know that there is something called Logcat. On looking at Logcat, I found multiple errors which I am not able to solve.

> 11-04 21:49:08.255 8217-8217/? E/System: elements.add : /data/app/com.example.darshan.justjava-2/base.apk  /data/app/com.example.darshan.justjava-2/base.apk   /data/app/com.example.darshan.justjava-2/base.apk
>
> 11-04 21:49:08.452 8217-8217/? E/System: elements.add : /data/app/com.example.darshan.justjava-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk  /data/app/com.example.darshan.justjava-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk   /data/app/com.example.darshan.justjava-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk
>
> 11-04 21:49:08.454 8217-8217/? E/System: elements.add : /data/app/com.example.darshan.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk  /data/app/com.example.darshan.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk   /data/app/com.example.darshan.justjava-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk

The third error in this list has figured 10 times in the Logcat.

Then, further when I click on the 'Order' button, there is a runtime error as shown below:

> 11-04 21:53:45.667 8217-8217/com.example.darshan.justjava E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.darshan.justjava, PID: 8217
>                                                                               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

And below this there are exceptions like

> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/icu/text/NumberFormat;
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.icu.text.NumberFormat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.darshan.justjava-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.darshan
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
>
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Can someone help me run my app on my phone? And also, why does my app run on the virtual device correctly even when there are runtime exceptions?

Thanks in advance.

PS: The project folder of this app is not in the default AndroidStudioProjects directory that Android Studio created for me. I created a seperate directory of my own. Told it just in case this might be the cause of the errors.

Comment: Which version of android your device runs? `NumberFormat` class was added in `api 24`

Comment: It runs Android 5.1.1 and API level is 22.

Comment: Thats why it doesn't run on your device.

Comment: So how to change the API level?

Comment: Either upgrade your phone to api 24 (if available), or change your code and don't use api 24 classes like `NumberFormat`, share your code for more

Comment: I think  @Victor Neves' solution and mine should solve all your problems. please let us know if you still have errors after

Comment: I think @KJNewtown and @VictorNeves solutions won't address the `api` problem of `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/icu/text/NumberFormat;` This class simply does not exist in `api` lower than 24, so it won't run on author's phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first errors:
In android, the "-" is not acceptable for a package name: `justjava-2` is the source of your errors, it seems that because of this, some files are not added to your device

You should recreate you project with a conform name such as `justjava_2`

Packages names only accept "a..z" , "_", "0..9" and must start with a letter

Comment: I hadn't named it... it was named by Android Studio itself

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you refering **android:onClick** through XML to a method that does not exist in your activity. If you want to refer an action like this way, you must have a method that returns **void** and has **View** as parameter in place on your activity.

```
public void myOrderAction(View view){
   //Do the "Order" stuff here
}
```

And in your XML

```
android:onClick="myOrderAction"
```

Comment: Yes, this should solve the onClick issue, also check my response below for the other errors about conformity

Comment: I already have a method for this. It ran perfectly on the Emulator.

Comment: How you came on this conclusion? the reason that `onClick` fails is: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/icu/text/NumberFormat;`

Comment: I think it is because the device on the emulator has API level 25. My phone has API level 22.